# How to execute "Yes/No" operation as long as I press "Yes" in bash?

Tags: bash, scripting

Suppose I have the Yes/No construction in bash script:

```
read -r -p "Yes or no?" response
if [[ $response =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]
 then 
 do ...
else
 exit 0
fi
```

I want this construction to be executed until I press "no". I.e., if I press "Yes", then after finalization of operation 'do ...' execution I want again 'Yes or no?' response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to keep asking for a response until it isn't one you want:

```
while true;
do
    read -r -p "Yes or no? " response   
    if [[ $response =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]
    then
        echo "You chose yes"
    else
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a while loop:

```
while
  read -r -p "Yes or no? " response &&
    [[ $response =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]
do
  ...
done
```

Or to make that code POSIX `sh` compatible so you don't need to have `bash` installed:

```
while
   printf 'Yes or No? ' &&
     read answer
do
  case $answer in
    ([yY][eE][sS] | [yY]) ...;;
    (*) break;;
  esac
done
```

Note that we also check for a failure exit status of `printf` (that could signal a broken pipe) and `read` (which would signal eof) as exit conditions of the loop as that's usually what you want.

In the case of `bash`'s `read -p`, the prompt will be issued by the shell process as `read` is built-in, so the shell will be killed when stdout becomes a broken pipe, but for `printf`, whether the shell or only `printf` will be killed will depend on the `sh` implementation as not all implementations have `printf` builtin. You may also want to report the `printf` error as an error of your script yourself for consistency:

```
while
   printf 'Yes or No? ' || exit # with the exit status of printf
   read answer # eof not considered as an error condition
do
  case $answer in
    ([yY][eE][sS] | [yY]) ...;;
    (*) break;;
  esac
done
```